# Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int?' in swift

Tags: swift

Why does this error occur without the last return nil?
Please understand that I am not good at English.
Thank you for your answers.

```
func firstNonConsecutive (_ arr: [Int]) -> Int? {
    var n = 0
    while n < arr.count - 1 {
        if arr[n] + 1 != arr[n + 1] {
            return arr[n+1]
        } else {
            n += 1
        }
    }
    //return nil (Why can't I have this?)
}
```

Comment: YOu need to return something, you need to return a `Int?`, be it an Integer or nil. If you don't, you aren't respecting the declaration of the method.

Comment: I don't understand your question. That code will not compile if your `return nil` is commented out, and **will** compile if that line is in place.